# encrypt and decrypt by aes from mysql server, read and write from c# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database with confidential data and a c# application which manages the database. I want the data are encrypted on the database and to read them from the application.

I could to use c# code to do that using AES by the class System.Security.Cryptography, but in that way I had to read the encrypted data and to decrypt them in the application.

So I don't want to do that using c# code, I would like to encrypt an decrypt the data from mysql server by AES doing the query's from the code application.

I have to say I want to do that for some tables and columns, then...
¿Is it possible to configurate the tableadapter to encrypt and decrypt the data? ¿What could I do if it wasn't possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can't really do it in the TableAdapter and even if you could that is still running c# code. What is your reason for not wanting to do it in the code? Or rather, does _the code_ mean any c#, or just for example inside a Winforms class?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173744.aspx this might be useful

Comment: @Awena useful link but this is mysql. I did find a similar thing for mysql tho: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: @Santi you can write a function in mysql DB ([here DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)) but not really understand why decrypt the DB side.

Comment: @Rhumborl Sure, but as you said even using these cryptographic functions it involves adapting the application code .. He should explain more

Comment: ok, I wanted to say not to make code inside Windows Form class. That's because, if I wanted to view the data in the server database directly and the data were encrypted from c# code (with System.Security.Cryptography class) made by me, I would view encrypted data there. However, if I encrypt the data by mysql server, I'll view the data directly by a "program" like Workbench or making a query in the server. Know what I mean? Thanks